# angularJS is it possible to update model without updating the view

Tags: angularjs

I'm integrating in an angularJS app a non angularJS module for dragging items in a list (or across several list items containers) and the lists themselves are bound to an object containing several arrays (the model) and an ng-repeat generates the items in each list. 
When performing a drag across lists, the drag module does it job perfectly in the html but doesn't update the model so i had to try that in its "dragend" event but the problem was that the lists twinkle and i wish i could avoid that effect. I need the view to be generated initially according to the model then disconnect the model and the view.

Comment: is it angular or angular js please confirm ?

Comment: yes, it's a v1.5

Comment: then it is angular js not angular

Comment: call $scope.apply after changing the items with your external module, or add a $scope.watch on the items your external module make changes to

Comment: @RahulSingh to be fair, that's more to do with how Google decided to confuse everyone with the names, than with Bardelman messing up. :)

Comment: Have you thought of cloning the original object and updating only the clone based on the changes you get from the "dragend" event? This way the original will remain as the model and a snapshot of the initial state and the clone can reflect manipulations without affecting the model.

Comment: @Jordumus i get that but they are trying to raise awareness to the same, it should be still denoted as Angular js as no where it mentioned you can tell angular js as angular that was developers discretion

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: [what about one way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354057/5621827)

Comment: @Vorcan i need update the model not a clone for further usage. The  lists do not only update by drag but from elsewhere, i need updates to be merged all together in the original model.