# AngularJS - Reducing the number of ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a register that lists people alphabetically from A to Z... Each person, Mr A for example, has a set of corresponding data `Histories`.

I have a table with a simple `ng-repeat` that displays the data for 12 cells (representing 12months).

If 12 months/cells worth of data is supplied, i show all the data, if only 5 months of data (anything less than 12) is provided, i call a service `srvEmptyCells` that calculates the remaining cells and displays in a darker colour.

The problem with this is, that i notice i am repeating the ng-repeat:

```
emptyCell in getEmptyCells
```

many many times which is impacting page performance given i have over 100 users.

Is there a way i save the number of empty cells for each particular user? And remove the need for the extra `ng-repeats`? Would a directive improve things?

Heres a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2UKDD1fvfYGMjX9oJqVu?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<table ng-repeat="data in myData" class="my-table">
  <caption>
    {{ data.Name }}
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Rate}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Effort</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Effort}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Advance</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Advance}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Previous</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Previous}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Current</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Current}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <td ng-repeat="history in data.Histories.slice(0, 12)" class="my-table-cell">
        {{history.Code}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)" class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, factoryGetJSONFile, srvEmptyCells) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData(function(data) {
    $scope.myData = data.MyData.Entries;
  });

  $scope.getEmptyCells = srvEmptyCells.getEmptyCells;

});

app.factory('srvEmptyCells', function() {
    return {
        getEmptyCells: function(len) {
            var emptyCells = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
                emptyCells.push(i);
            }
            return emptyCells;
        }
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `$scope.myData` by adding a cached version of `data.Histories.slice(0, 12)` and `getEmptyCells(data.Histories.slice(0, 12).length)` and using `ng-repeat` on those instead.
This way you'd save repeating those calls over and over again.

A better way, if you can modify the response, would be to do this service side rather than on the client. Why to return more than 12 histories if you won't need them?

It is hard to know if this will fix your performance issue, as there are many ng-repeats per row, but it will be faster than before at least.

Sample on caching client side;

```
factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData(function(data) {
   $scope.myData = data.MyData.Entries;

   for (int i=0; i < $scope.myData.length; i++) {
     var current = $scope.myData[i];
     current.nonEmptyCells = current.Histories.slice(0, 12);
     current.emptyCells =  srvEmptyCells.getEmptyCells(current.nonEmptyCells.length);
   }
});
```

then change your ng-repeats in the html to:

```
<td ng-repeat="history in data.nonEmptyCells" class="my-table-cell">
```

and

```
<td ng-repeat="emptyCell in data.emptyCells" class="empty"></td>
```

updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/92S2rNNhBEyXZVsCI2M8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately i cant change what data is being returning. The cache solution sounds interesting, any examples?

Comment: check now, there might be a way of doing this by calling .memoize function but I have to leave now

Comment: Thanks for the example, can the for loop be placed in my Controller rather than Factory? Memoization looks interesting, but i've never used it and wouldnt know where to start? Would it be simple in this case?

Comment: Just realised that is in the controller

Comment: Updated my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2UKDD1fvfYGMjX9oJqVu?p=preview but <td> is not repeating. Can see correct values coming in the console.log.

Comment: I fixed the response, it should be `data.emptyCells` in the `ng-repeat`

Comment: are you able to update the Plunker? I cant see where data. is coming from?

Comment: here is the plunkr updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/92S2rNNhBEyXZVsCI2M8?p=preview.
You had some errors when you copied the answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can reduce the number of `ng-repeat`'s to only **2**.

You just need to change a little bit your approach. Instead of doing `splice` on every `ng-repeat`, use a list/array of indexes with a predefined length. Then, iterate over that list of indexes and for each index check if there is an item in the same position of the `data.Histories` array. If there is, then it's a `'my-table-cell'` otherwise it's an `'empty'` cell (`ng-class` helps you defining that).

Then use the same logic for the fields, instead of having 1 `ng-repeat` for each field, try to define a list/array of fields and then use only 1 `ng-repeat` to iterate over that list.

The final result should be something like this:

```
<table ng-repeat="data in myData" class="my-table">
  <caption>
    {{ data.Name }}
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <th>{{field}}</th>
      <td ng-repeat="idx in indexes" ng-class="{ 'my-table-cell': data.Histories[idx][field], 'empty': !data.Histories[idx][field]}">
        {{data.Histories[idx][field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And on the `MainCtrl` add the following lines:

```
// the list of indexes could be populated dynamically...
$scope.indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$scope.fields = ['Rate', 'Effort', 'Advance', 'Previous', 'Current', 'Code'];
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WKdDl3gVYB27YnruBv5N?p=preview)**

Comment: @bmliete - Wow! Great option.. What if on the front end i wanted to display 'Previous Amount' instead of 'Previous', but cant change my JSON file.

Comment: Yes you can change the order as you want. To display a different label just use Objects instead of Strings and do some little changes on the HTML. Check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/s32GHTgQ1Il41dbwMtQ0?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why when a cell is null it is not being darkened on the front end?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `field` validation in the `ng-class` expression. Check the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/s32GHTgQ1Il41dbwMtQ0?p=preview) now.

Comment: I think your approach is great. When writing Angular apps i use this question to ensure my watches are kept to a minimum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499909/how-to-count-total-number-of-watches-on-a-page  After i added a couple of ng-if's because i need to add classes and data-contents for certain labels, the number of watches nearly treble, here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/n9facqC0OcMS4UpEvMDF?p=preview   the page load is naturally very slow as a result.