# Angularjs: why there are 3 watchers for 1 binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch, angularjs-bindings

Please take a look at the screenshot given below

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above there are #3 watchers for a single binding.

Can anyone please elaborate why is it so?

P.S: I am using AngularJS Batarang for checking the performance.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.name = 'vikas bansal';
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Angular Batarang has a wrong counter of watchers. I checked with few different sources, and all except AngularJS Batarang show me single watcher on your code. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499909/how-to-count-total-number-of-watches-on-a-page) with function:

```
(function () { 
    var root = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('body'));

    var watchers = [];

    var f = function (element) {
        angular.forEach(['$scope', '$isolateScope'], function (scopeProperty) { 
            if (element.data() && element.data().hasOwnProperty(scopeProperty)) {
                angular.forEach(element.data()[scopeProperty].$$watchers, function (watcher) {
                    watchers.push(watcher);
                });
            }
        });

        angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
            f(angular.element(childElement));
        });
    };

    f(root);

    // Remove duplicate watchers
    var watchersWithoutDuplicates = [];
    angular.forEach(watchers, function(item) {
        if(watchersWithoutDuplicates.indexOf(item) < 0) {
             watchersWithoutDuplicates.push(item);
        }
    });

    console.log(watchersWithoutDuplicates.length);
})();
```

And you can check [**Watchers**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk) extension for chrome. Both show 1 watcher.