# How to count Angular Watchers on Page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I accurately count the number of watchers on a page?

I found a few different articles on how to do it, but they all give me different counts, so I'm struggling to find which is the correct way.

There is a StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499909/how-to-count-total-number-of-watches-on-a-page) with the following code:

```
(function () { 
var root = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('body'));

var watchers = [];

var f = function (element) {
    angular.forEach(['$scope', '$isolateScope'], function (scopeProperty) { 
        if (element.data() && element.data().hasOwnProperty(scopeProperty)) {
            angular.forEach(element.data()[scopeProperty].$$watchers, function (watcher) {
                watchers.push(watcher);
            });
        }
    });

    angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
        f(angular.element(childElement));
    });
};

f(root);

// Remove duplicate watchers
var watchersWithoutDuplicates = [];
angular.forEach(watchers, function(item) {
    if(watchersWithoutDuplicates.indexOf(item) < 0) {
         watchersWithoutDuplicates.push(item);
    }
});

console.log(watchersWithoutDuplicates.length);
})();
```

When I test it on the Angularjs.org homepage, it gives me 132 watchers.

I then found a Medium post [here](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef#.kf1idnvp9), with the following code:

```
function getWatchers(root) {
  root = angular.element(root || document.documentElement);
  var watcherCount = 0;

  function getElemWatchers(element) {
    var isolateWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$isolateScope);
    var scopeWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$scope);
    var watchers = scopeWatchers.concat(isolateWatchers);
    angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
      watchers = watchers.concat(getElemWatchers(angular.element(childElement)));
    });
    return watchers;
  }

  function getWatchersFromScope(scope) {
    if (scope) {
      return scope.$$watchers || [];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  return getElemWatchers(root);
}
getWatchers().length
```

Testing this on Angularjs.org homepage returns 152 watchers.

Using simply `angular.element('body').scope().$$watchersCount` returns 80.

I understand that the SO code removes duplicates, is it removing duplicates that are watching the same expression (so there will only be one watcher listed for an expression like `!visible`), or it's removing duplicate watcher objects?

**Update:**

I realize the discrepancy is from duplicates. But, do duplicate watchers affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

> This script will help you identify how many watchers are there on your
>   page

just paste  the below script on your browser's console and it will tell you the watcher count on your page

```
 function getWatchers(root) {
  root = angular.element(root || document.documentElement);
  var watcherCount = 0;

  function getElemWatchers(element) {
    var isolateWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$isolateScope);
    var scopeWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$scope);
    var watchers = scopeWatchers.concat(isolateWatchers);
    angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
      watchers = watchers.concat(getElemWatchers(angular.element(childElement)));
    });
    return watchers;
  }

  function getWatchersFromScope(scope) {
    if (scope) {
      return scope.$$watchers || [];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  return getElemWatchers(root);
}
getWatchers().length
```