# Can't find cause of memory leak

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, momentjs

I am having a memory leak inside my AngularJS application and I don't know what would cause this. I have done a couple of snapshots inside Chrome's dev tools and there is unreleased memory which contains information related to moment.js. Inside the dev tools window I can see a parent "(array)", which contains other arrays filled with a bunch of objects related to the moment.js library. Here's a picture:

[image]

Does anybody have a hint on what I should check? Or has someone dealt with this as well? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like moment.tz library data. But the array inself takes only 1M of memory. The screenshot does not show what's below.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the number of watchers behind the scene? Here is the post about [How to count total number of watches on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499909/how-to-count-total-number-of-watches-on-a-page)

Significant number of watchers can slow down your tool drastically - I do not know if in your case this is the source of problem but you can give it a try.